# how to pass variables from java to jsp in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

in a spring framework I want to pass some variables(objects) to jsp page. I can pass one object with:

```
 ModelAndView modelAndView= new ModelAndView("JspPageName", "message", message); 
 return message
```

But how can I send more than one objects from java to jsp. Actually I know that I can make a object array and send this array, however I wonder the best way of doşng this
My code which send the datas to jsp is this:

```
@Controller
public class DomainEkleController {
    private DomainJDBCTemplate  domainJDBCTemplate;
    private MemurJDBCTemplate memurJDBCTemplate;
    @ModelAttribute("Domain")
    public Domain getDomain()
    {
        return new Domain();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("domainJDBCTemplate")
    public void setDomainJDBCTemplate(DomainJDBCTemplate domainJDBCTemplate) {
        this.domainJDBCTemplate = domainJDBCTemplate;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("memurJDBCTemplate")
    public void setMemurJDBCTemplate(MemurJDBCTemplate memurJDBCTemplate) {
        this.memurJDBCTemplate = memurJDBCTemplate;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/DomainEkle")
    public ModelAndView domainEkle() {

        List<Memur> memurlar=memurJDBCTemplate.getAll();
        System.out.println(memurlar);
        /*for(Memur x:memurlar)
        {
            System.out.println(x.getIsim());
        }*/
        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        ModelAndView domain_ekle= new ModelAndView("DomainEkle", "message", message);
        return domain_ekle;
    }




    @RequestMapping(value="/DomainEkle",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView domain_eklendi_fonksiyon(@ModelAttribute("Domain")Domain domain,   ModelMap model)
    {




        model.addAttribute("domain_adi", domain.getDomain_adi());
        model.addAttribute("sunucu_no", domain.getSunucu_no());
        model.addAttribute("tarih", domain.getTarih());
        model.addAttribute("ilgili_memur_no",domain.getIlgili_memur_no());

        String message="Domain Kaydi Yapilmistir!";
        ModelAndView dm_eklendi=new ModelAndView("DomainEkle","message",message);

        domainJDBCTemplate.addDomain(domain);
        return dm_eklendi;

      }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will notice `ModelAndView` has a constructor that accepts a [`Map<String, ?>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html#ModelAndView%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%29)

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("someView", map);
```

So construct a map to hold the model attributes

```
 Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
 map.put("attrib1", someAttrib);
```

You can put as many key-value paired objects in this map and pass it to the constructor or call the

```
mav.addAllObjects(map);
```

method to add all the attributes. These attributes will end up in the `HttpServletRequest` where they will be available to the JSP.

This ends up being equivalent to passing a `Model` or `ModelMap` as an argument to your handler methods. Same as you do in your `domain_eklendi_fonksiyon()` method.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge I am very new to java and spring thanks :)

Comment: @aliinsan You are welcome. I recommend carefully reading the javadoc of the spring-mvc classes. The official documentation is also very clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
mav.addObject("data1", somdeData1);
mav.addObject("data2", somdeData2);
...
```

to add additional model attributes.

Note that you don't have to create the `ModelAndView` object yourself. You can add a `Model` parameter to your controller methods which is added by Spring when the method is called. You can simply use this model to add your data. After that you need only to return the view name.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/DomainEkle")
public String domainEkle(Model model) {
  model.addAtribute("data", data);
  return "myViewName";
}
```