# Difference between @ModelAttribute and HttpServletRequest Attribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I use spring mvc and I want to undestand some stuff.
At this code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/enregistrerLostCard") 
public  @ResponseBody
void enregistrerLostCard(@ModelAttribute(value="auth") Auth auth2, HttpServletRequest request) {    

    Auth auth1 = (Auth) request.getAttribute("auth");

    System.out.println(auth2.getLogin()); //print the right value
    System.out.println(auth1.getLogin()); //i got nullpointer exception

}
```

`@ModelAttribute(value="auth")` and `request.getAttribute("auth")` isn't the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpServletRequest` is a `Servlet` container managed object. Its attribute store holds attributes that are useful in any part of the request handling by the `Servlet` container.

`Model`, `ModelMap`, `ModelAndView`, etc. are managed by Spring MVC (the `DispatcherServlet` stack). The attributes inside those are useful to the Spring side of the application.

In some cases, the `Model` attributes will be inserted into the `HttpServletRequest` attributes if needed. This typically happens when your handler method returns a `String` value as a view name. The model attributes will be pushed as `HttpServletRequest` attributes so that they can be used in the view, for example, in jsps.

Related:

- [how to pass variables from java to jsp in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677117/how-to-pass-variables-from-java-to-jsp-in-spring/18677172#18677172)

Comment: but in the related post you said `These attributes will end up in the HttpServletRequest where they will be available to the JSP.` !

Comment: @Youssef I said that in this answer too.

Comment: but why `@ModelAttribute(value="auth")` doesn't end up in the `HttpServletRequest`'s attribute? i'm little confused.

Comment: @Youssef Because the addition happens at a much later step of the `DispatcherServlet` `doDispatch` method. You should check out the source code.