# What's the difference usage of Model and HttpServletRequest in SpringMVC?Can HttpServletRequest replace Model totally?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using [spring-mvc](/questions/tagged/spring-mvc) to develop my web projects,but I want to pass parameters to the jsp pages,I found a problem and want to have an answer:

**What's the difference usage of  [Model](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/) and [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) in SpringMVC?Can HttpServletRequest replace Model totally?**

I found I can use both of them to pass parameter and I found they seems to have the same effect.Now I want to know when to use [Model](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/) and when to use [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html),I feel [Model](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/) seems to be a duplicate class,can it be replaced by [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) totally?

For example,if I want to pass a user list and the current date to a jsp page via [spring-mvc](/questions/tagged/spring-mvc),I can do it in three different ways:

- Only use **Model**

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "queryUserPage")
public String queryUserPage(int pageNo,int pageSize,Model model) {
    PageBean<UserModel> pageBean = new PageBean<UserModel>();
    pageBean.setPageNo(pageNo);
    pageBean.setPageSize(pageSize);
    pageBean.setResultList(userService.queryUserPage(pageBean));
    model.addAttribute("pageBean", pageBean);
    model.addAttribute("currentTime",new Date());
    return "settings/userManagement.jsp";
}
```

- Only use **HttpServletRequest**

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "queryUserPage")
public String queryUserPage(int pageNo,int pageSize,HttpServletRequest request) {
    PageBean<UserModel> pageBean = new PageBean<UserModel>();
    pageBean.setPageNo(pageNo);
    pageBean.setPageSize(pageSize);
    pageBean.setResultList(userService.queryUserPage(pageBean));
    request.setAttribute("pageBean", pageBean);
    request.setAttribute("currentTime",new Date());
    return "settings/userManagement.jsp";
}
```

- Use **HttpServletRequest** and **Model** at the same time

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "queryUserPage")
public String queryUserPage(int pageNo,int pageSize,HttpServletRequest request,Model model) {
    PageBean<UserModel> pageBean = new PageBean<UserModel>();
    pageBean.setPageNo(pageNo);
    pageBean.setPageSize(pageSize);
    pageBean.setResultList(userService.queryUserPage(pageBean));
    request.setAttribute("pageBean", pageBean);
    model.addAttribute("currentTime",new Date());
    return "settings/userManagement.jsp";
}
```

All these 3 methods are okay,but I don't know the advantage to use **Model** instead of using **HttpServletRequest**.Can anybody tell me when to use **Model** and when to use **HttpServletRequest**?What's the advantage of **Model**? Can it be replaced by **HttpServletRequest** totally?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Poori,it's not a duplicate questions,please read my question carefully!

Comment: @Poori,please reopen my question!you don't read it carefully!

Comment: its not marked as duplicate...its just a possibility...no need to worry..it needs 10 flags not only one...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between @ModelAttribute and HttpServletRequest Attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927686/difference-between-modelattribute-and-httpservletrequest-attribute)

Comment: @Prasanna: it needs 5 votes, not 10 (or just one from a `spring` gold-star).

Comment: @lucumt: please do not add voting commentary into your question, and especially not at the start, where it makes no contextual sense for new readers. You can add comments here in reply to suggestions that something is a duplicate, and if you do so please explain _why_ you believe it is a different case. Close voters are able to withdraw their vote if you can persuade them.

Comment: Worth bearing in mind: to a native English speaker, "please read my question carefully" carries an implication of "are you stupid, or careless?", so it may be best to avoid that! `:-)`

Answer (score 3):

Choice is left to developer.But few things you need to keep in mind.

If you use `HttpServletRequest` then you have to explicitly map the variables and taking the variables from front end also(`request.getAttribute`).

There is no such thing that this is better,it's just your wish.Since **both are request scope.**
But if you use **`Model`** you have several advantages.

- No need to map since it will automatically find by path name(`@ModelAttribute`).
- Validations can be done just by using annotations(`@Valid`).

Like this you can also find ask the differences b/w `@RequestParam` or `@ModelAttribute` and `HttpServletRequest`.

Sometimes `Model` also go through as `HttpServletRequest`.

Only thing is `HttpServletRequest` is handled by `ServletContainer`.`Model` by `DispatcherServlet stack`.

Finally it's left to developer,he/she can you according to their needs.